# Linq With Entity Framework Error - Unable to create a constant value of type

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I got the following error :
Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'FileCombined'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

I am using the following code:

```
var o1 = new FileCombined (){ ScholarshipID = 3, FileDescription = "smt" };
var o2 = new FileCombined() { ScholarshipID = 10, FileDescription = "smt" };

List <FileCombined> list = new FileCombined[] { o1, o2 }.ToList();

var data = (from scholarship in db.ScholarshipRequests  
            join file in list on scholarship.ScholarshipRequestID equals file.ScholarshipID
            select new { ScholarshipID = scholarship.ScholarshipRequestID, FileDescription = file.FileDescription }).ToList();
```

if I change the order of the linq expression , the query works fine:

```
var o1 = new FileCombined (){ ScholarshipID = 3, FileDescription = "smt" };
var o2 = new FileCombined() { ScholarshipID = 10, FileDescription = "smt" };

List <FileCombined> list = new FileCombined[] { o1, o2 }.ToList();

var data = (from file in list
            join scholarship in db.ScholarshipRequests on file.ScholarshipID equals scholarship.ScholarshipRequestID  
            select new FileCombined (){ ScholarshipID = scholarship.ScholarshipRequestID, FileDescription = file.FileDescription }).ToList();
```

can anyone explain or find the solution? 
I need the first query to work, because i have more complicated query in the continuous code

Comment: Is ScholarshipRequests attached to a database? If it is in the first code example, LINQ will try to run the query on the DB which won't know about your List<FileCombined> object.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Maarten's answer I would say you can also remove the join and use `Contains`, because in your case you'll get the same result (I suppose the `list` will not get huge). You can then look-up the `FileDescription` in the list (and I would maybe create dictionary).

```
var list2 = list.Select(x => x.ScholarshipID);
var data = (from scholarship in db.ScholarshipRequests
            where list2.Contains(scholarship.ScholarshipRequestID)
            select new { ScholarshipID = scholarship.ScholarshipRequestID }).ToList();
// do the lookup in "list" and get result
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `list` is a variable-in-memory, and `db.ScholarshipRequests` is a table in a context, this is indeed not possible. You cannot expect EF to create a query which joins a database table with an in-memory collection.

You can load the table in memory, but please be warned that this loads the entire table in memory, which can/will cause performance issues.

Like this (I've added `.ToList()` after `db.ScholarshipRequests`):

```
var data = (from scholarship in db.ScholarshipRequests.ToList()
            join file in list on scholarship.ScholarshipRequestID equals file.ScholarshipID
            select new { ScholarshipID = scholarship.ScholarshipRequestID, FileDescription = file.FileDescription }).ToList();
```